# Get Custom Category Attribute Value On List Page : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom, category-attribute, list.phtml

i have created custom category attribute now i want to get the attribute value on list.phtml page i can i achieve this in magento2.

```
<?php if($category->getColThreeCategory()): ?>
        <ol class="grid-product-type products list items product-items col-3-wizard">
    <?php else: ?>
            <ol class="grid-product-type products list items product-items">
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create category custom attribute with used_in_product_listing and visible_on_front set to ture

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
        'col_three_category',
        [
            // ...
            'used_in_product_listing' => true, // for category pages
            'visible_on_front' => true, // for frontend??
            'is_used_in_grid' => true, // for category pages
            'is_visible_in_grid' => true // for category pages
        ]
    );
```

Then you can get this custom attribute value like this.

```
$category->getColThreeCategory()
    // or
    $category->getData('col_three_category');
```

Comment: i am getting error on search page?

Comment: Call to a member function getData() on null

Comment: on search page it will not work becuase search page is not current category page so  $category object will not work you need to add condtion like 
$currentCategory = $registry->registry('current_category');
if ($currentCategory) {
    // Custom code
}

Comment: for magento2 this code?

Comment: how you getting this $category->getColThreeCategory()
the $category object in your code ?

Comment: yes i have $category

Comment: $category = $_config->getCurrentCategory();//get current category

Comment: So add condtion like 
if($_config->getCurrentCategory())

here category custom attribute code 

endif;